# How is number of conjugacy class related to the order of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $c(G)$ denote the number of conjugacy classes of a group $G$. I have to show that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf _{|G|=n}c(G)=\infty.$$ That is, I have to show that $\exists $ a function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that if $c(g)\leq n, $ then $|G|\leq f(n).$

I know that if $G$ is a finite group such that any two non-identity elements in $G$ are conjugate, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. The proof is simple, infact:

> It can easily be shown that $G$ acts transitively by conjugation on $G \setminus \{e\}$. Then, by  orbit-stabilizer theorem, the claim follows.

I wonder if similar idea could be useful somehow. But I can't think of any to prove the claim above. Please help!

Comment: Your problem isn't properly stated. For a given $n$, there will, in general, be many groups $G$ with $|G|=n$ and this will give you many different values of $c(G)$ for a given $n$. So it doesn't make sense to talk about the limit of $c(G)$ as $|G|$ tends to infinity, because $c(G)$ is not a function of $|G|$.

Comment: @RobArthan What they probably meant was 

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{|G|=n}c(G)$$

Comment: @Alex Youcis: I dare say you are right. In which case the hint for the OP is "what is $c(G)$ if $G$ is abelian?".

Comment: If $G$ is abelian, conjugacy classes consists of singleton sets. That is $c(G)=|G|$. Hence, limit goes to infinity. Correct? What if $G$ is not abelian?

Comment: The question is stated clearly in the third sentence of the post beginning "That is" (except that it should be $|G| \le f(n)$), and considering $G$ abelian doesn't help answer it! Maybe this can be done by number theory, but I am not sure. If a group of order $k$ has $n$ classes, then you have $n-1$ divisors of $k$ summing to $k-1$. If you fix $n$, then I wonder whether that is possible for arbitrarily large $k$.

Comment: @monomorphic: to avoid further confusion, you could clarify that what you want to show is that: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \inf_{|G|=n} c(G)=\infty$$

Comment: sure. I will make a edit!

Comment: This question is discussed here: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/There_are_finitely_many_finite_groups_with_bounded_number_of_conjugacy_classes Unfortunately I do not have a reference for the sum of Egyptian fractions statement used in the proof, but it is probably well-known!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a result that goes back to Landau (1903). A proof is also given in the short article "A bound for the number of conjugacy classes in a group" by M. Newman. Here is the proof from that article, but the idea is pretty much the same as in all the other proofs.

**Lemma:** Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be positive integers such that $1/x_1 + \cdots+ 1/x_n = 1$. Then  $\max x_i \leq n^{2^{n-1}}$.

**Proof:** Assume $x_1 \leq \cdots \leq x_n$. Now $x_1 \leq n$, as otherwise $1/x_i > 1/n$ for all $n$ and then $1/x_1 + \cdots + 1/x_n > 1$. For $1 \leq r \leq n-1$, we have

$$\frac{1}{x_{r+1}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x_{n}} = 1 - (\frac{1}{x_{1}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x_{r}}) = \frac{y}{x_1x_2\cdots x_r}$$

where $y$ is a positive integer. Then

$$\frac{n-r}{x_{r+1}} \geq \frac{y}{x_1x_2 \cdots x_r} \geq \frac{1}{x_1x_2 \cdots x_r}$$

which implies $x_{r+1} \leq (n-r) x_1 \cdots x_r \leq n x_1 \cdots x_r$. Because $x_1 \leq n$, we see by induction that $x_r \leq n^{2^{r-1}}$ for all $1 \leq r \leq n$.

We apply the lemma to prove

**Claim:** Let $G$ be a finite group with $k$ conjugacy classes. Then

$$|G| \leq k^{2^{k-1}}$$

**Proof:** Suppose $G$ has conjugacy classes of orders $c_1, \ldots, c_k$. Then $c_1 + \cdots + c_k = |G|$, so

$$\frac{1}{|G|/c_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{|G|/c_k} = 1$$

By applying the lemma, we see that $|G| \leq \max |G|/c_i \leq k^{2^{k-1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $G$ non-abelian, take for instance $G=D_n$, the dihedral group of order $2n$. It is well-known that 
$$c(D_n)= \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{n+3}{2} & \mbox{for}
& n \text{ odd} \\ \frac{n+6}{2} & \mbox{for} & n \text{ even}
\end{array}\right.$$ This also implies the infinity of your limit.

Comment: But this is just one example. I have to prove for arbitrary $G$. Or did I miss your point?

Comment: You are calculating a limsup, hence one subseries that goes to infinity determines that this goes to infinity.

Comment: @NickyHekster I think you misunderstood the question on this occasion! It is a liminf, not limsup.