# Non abelian group with some nice properties

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Are there examples of finite non-abelian groups of order $k$ where the number of conjugacy classes is $O(\log{k})$? Or is there any reason this is not obviously possible? I know that there lower bounds on the number of conjugacy classes as a function of the order of the group (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034333/how-is-number-of-conjugacy-class-related-to-the-order-of-a-group)). Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm also interested in groups where the number of conjugacy classes grows *slowly* as a function of the order, i.e, $\kappa(G) = O(\log^c{k})$ for any constant $c$ that is independent of other parameters of the group.

Comment: Digging around a little, this appears to me, shockingly, to be an open problem. See https://people.math.wisc.edu/~nboston/finalgps.pdf, https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.2590, and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58794/bounds-on-number-of-conjugacy-classes-in-terms-of-number-of-elements-of-a-group . At the very least one of the results quoted in that MO thread shows that this is not possible for nilpotent groups (and so for $p$-groups).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The paper by Nigel Boston you linked has a line that says: "Kovacs and Leedham-Green [7] produced for each odd
prime $p$ a group $G_p$ of order $p^p$ with less than $p^3 = (\log_p|G_p|)^3$
classes." I tried reading the paper mentioned, but it looks a bit terse. But if I understood it correctly, doesn't this answer my question?

Comment: Not as written; if $k = p^p$ then $p^3$ is something like $\frac{(\log k)^3}{\log \log k}$ which grows faster than $\log k$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Indeed. Actually, I'm interested in groups where the number of conjugacy classes grows polylogarithmically in the order of the group ($O(\log^c{|G|})$ for some constant $c$ that is independent of the parameters of the group) - so the group cited in the paper is an interesting class of groups.  Are you aware of other examples, with this relaxation? I'm editing the question to reflect this.

Comment: In that case the Kovacs and Leedham-Green examples qualify and it's the only family of examples I know of.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see - Thanks! If you can post this as an answer, I can accept it, since it answers what I was looking for (It will be nice if you can give a short description of the group as well, but that's not necessary)